# Python SFTP: Can you differentiate socket.error and PermissionError in exception clause?

Tags: python, sockets, exception, error-handling, permissions

I am currently trying to catch an error if the connection is closed in the middle of my script and to catch if I don't have Permission to open a File.

When I try to catch the socket.error Error i get this:

```
Socket is closed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./sFTPscript11.py", line 257, in uploadSFTP
    sftp.put(config.output_local + list_localSFTP, config.tmp_remote + list_localSFTP)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 759, in put
    return self.putfo(fl, remotepath, file_size, callback, confirm)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 714, in putfo
    with self.file(remotepath, "wb") as fr:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 372, in open
    t, msg = self._request(CMD_OPEN, filename, imode, attrblock)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 812, in _request
    num = self._async_request(type(None), t, *arg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 837, in _async_request
    self._send_packet(t, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/sftp.py", line 198, in _send_packet
    self._write_all(out)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/sftp.py", line 162, in _write_all
    n = self.sock.send(out)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 801, in send
    return self._send(s, m)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/channel.py", line 1198, in _send
    raise socket.error("Socket is closed")
OSError: Socket is closed
```

Which would be right, but I am getting this output through my PermissionError Exception.

And I don't know why.

Comment: There is nothing in that exception stacktrace that indicates a socket error.

Comment: oh I am sorry, that was wrong. I changed the question.

Comment: ok, now with your edit you have an exception stacktrace that has no information to suggest the exception is caused by a permission problem on the remote host. This is caused by attempting to use a socket that is already closed. So how do you know this is related to a permission problem?

Comment: Because I closed the Process manually to see if the Exception is catching the Error which it didnt. this exception stacktrace gets printed by 'except (PermissionError,IOError= as err: 'and not by 'except socket.error as err:'

Answer (score 0):

I solved this Problem myself and I know that this method is not the most elegant way.

```
except Exception as err:
    if 'Permission denied' in str(err):
       print('Permission Error')
    elif 'Socket is closed' in str(err):
       print('Connection Lost')
```